# Missing Significance level for Pearson Chi-Squared Test

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm trying to switch over from Stata and R to Python's statsmodels. I find I can do most of what I need but am missing something when running negative binomial regression -- specifically, the significance level for the chi-squared test. For example, with a model like this:

```
mod1 = smf.glm(formula='like_count ~ source + followers_count + \
    mission_focus_Patient_advocacy + Assets + hashtag_count, data=df,   \
    missing='drop', hasconst=None, family=sm.families.NegativeBinomial()).fit()
```

From this I can run mod1.summary() and get the main model results, as seen below:

[image]

Typically I would report the number of observations, which is there, the log-likelihood value, which is there, the Pearson chi-squared value, which is also there, along with three pieces of missing information: 1) the significance level for the chi-squared test, 2) a pseudo-R2 value such as McFadden pseudo-R-squared (I know I should not do this but reviewers generally want to see it), and 3) the results of the Likelihood-ratio chi-squared test (to show that Poisson model would not work instead).

My question is, how can I get these things? I know I can access specific model results individually, including:

```
mod1.llf           #get Log-Likelihood
mod1.pearson_chi2  #get chi-square
```

Checking the online documentation I can't find the parameters I'm looking for. By contrast, I know that with a logit model, for instance, I could get the following:

```
mod_logit.llf        #get Log-Likelihood
mod_logit.llr        #get chi-square
mod_logit.llr_pvalue #get sig. level of chi-square test
mod_logit.prsquared  #get pseudo-rsquared
```

But in negative binomial I can't seem to find a way to get the significance level for the chi-squared test. At a bare minimum I'd like to get this. Ideally, I'd also be able to get the likelihood-ratio test results as well as a pseudo-r-squared. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Just in general: GLM is a one parameter family and does not estimate the NegativeBinomial dispersion parameter. The user needs to plug that in. However, in discrete there is a NegativeBinomial MLE class that estimates the dispersion parameter (either nb1 or nb2) and should contain the same or similar result statistic as Logit. (In cases like this it's helpful to open an issue with statsmodels, although you might get a "recipe" for the calculation faster on stackoverflow.)

Comment: Thanks for that insight but I'm afraid you lost me. When you're talking about the "dispersion parameter" I'm guessing that refers to the likelihood ratio test I mentioned -- the one to determine whether negative binomial is preferred over poisson. Is that correct? And if so, then you lost me again regarding how that contains the same statistic as logit (because I would not run that test with logit). In short, either you've misunderstood my question or -- more likely -- you have a much deeper understanding of this and you're talking over my head. So could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: part 1: Poisson assumes variance is equal to mean. Negative Binomial has variance proportional to mean, where the extra parameter reflects over dispersion. This is an extra parameter that needs to be estimated, and statsmodels.NegativeBinomial does so. The difference between NegativeBinomial and it's Poisson special case could be tested directly as a restriction on this Parameter, or with a Likelihood Ratio test as you mentioned.

Comment: part 2: statsmodels implements many of the GLM models in two ways, for example as NegativeBinomial family in GLM or directly as an MLE model. Given that those two were written based on different traditions, one statistics, the other econometrics, the available results have not been made completely consistent yet. So the MLE models `NegativeBinomial`, `Logit`, `Probit` and `Poisson` define or inherit the same methods that you listed, `llr`. `llr_pvalue` and `prsquared`. The equivalent `GLM` models don't have all of these attributes, but have others that are not available for the MLE models.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Much appreciated. I still don't fully understand how to implement the tests you mentioned so if you have any link to recommend please let me know. But thanks for comments already. Helpful!

Comment: `result = smf.negativebinomial(formula, data).fit()` should give you the attributes like `prsquared`. There is no LR test available currently for NegativeBinomial versus Poisson, the function can be copied from another model but needs to be checked if the parameter count is correct. For example https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/2440/files

Comment: Related to LR test: I doubt that the standard LR test between NegativeBinomial and Poisson is correct because the parameter for overdispersion is on the boundary of the parameter space. I'm not sure because I only looked at score tests for over or underdispersion in Poisson.

Comment: For some reason the 'result' method you gave isn't working for me. It gives a value for 'LL-Null' but all other model parameters are 'nan'. Can't figure out why.

Comment: Obtaining nans is a different issue, and I have no guess. I just tried a simple example and get all the expected results. I'm working with statmodels master, but this should work correctly since at least the 0.6 version.

Comment: about LR test: See last point in Achim's answer http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127505/compare-poisson-and-negative-binomial-regression-with-lr-test